# Exporting gltf animation file from blender to panda3d

Tags: python, blender, panda3d

I am making a game using panda3d but every time I try to animate the actor, the all file becomes distorted. I'm using characters from Blender.

I tried using both bam and gltf files but they are both giving distorted results. I'm expecting to see the same animation I see in Blender.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.